# Filter Box Web-scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

Need to change a filter box to show date range I need before downloading table. Want to pull information a couple times a day and link it to Power BI dashboard. It's internal company info, so you can't look at the element info yourself, unfortunately.

Starting pic:

[image]

End result needed: -date after and will need to always be the current date.

[image]

Process:
GUI process to change:

1. Click on box
2. Click on Equals word --drop box appears.
3. Click on Between
4. Click on Last Month
5. Drop box -- click on custom
6. Click on first box and enter date
7. Click on second box enter date
8. Click on green checkmark to close
9. Wait for update

Final green check has to be clicked: [image]

If it isn't enough info, that's fine. Was able to use Selenium to log in and get there, but can't get this box after 2 days of trying.

Code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from Ekos_login_info import username, password

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get("https://login.goekos.com/default.aspx")
username_elem = driver.find_element_by_id("txtUsername")
pass_elem = driver.find_element_by_id("txtPassword")
username_elem.send_keys(username)
pass_elem.send_keys(password)
btn_elem = driver.find_element_by_id("btnLogin")
btn_elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
import time
time.sleep(5)
reports_elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Reports")
reports_elem.click()
time.sleep(5)
cogs_elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Cost Of Goods Sold - With Customer")
cogs_elem.click()
time.sleep(5)
```

I have tried to click by id, class, text element-- just about everything I could think of, but it just won't work after I get to this page.

Here is what the finished element section looks like if that will help:
[image]

Comment: Is this for a regression test or just for data acquisition? In case of the latter, it might be worth a try to just directly send the GET requests to the server instead of emulating browser events.

Comment: How far are you able to execute your events? Is the first box not opening at all or are you just not able to manipulate the filter settings once the box is open?

Comment: This is for data acquisition. I can't manipulate the box at all. It never recognizes any items in the box so I can click.

Comment: So for data acquisition, it is usually preferred to directly download the data instead of making the detour of emulating human interaction on the browser level. I cannot say, if this is applicable to your website, but you could examine the requests your browser sends when you view the data by hand and try to use Python's [requests package](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) and  [beautiful soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to send the same requests in a script and parse the resulting data.

Comment: Thanks, I am just not advanced enough to know if that will work. I will check out some resources online this weekend and see if I can get to the data.